# Rota não funciona no Vue.js - Vai para a ' / ' ao invés de ' /login '

Tags: vue.js, rotas, vue-router

Boa noite, pessoal!

Estou começando a aprender e estou criando o meu primeiro projeto com Vue.js.

Acontece que criei uma rota '/login' mas o componente que carrega é o 'Content' que tá na raiz da aplicação. Estou olhando o código e não consigo encontrar o problema. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Se eu coloco localhost:3001 ou localhost:3001/login aparece exatamente a mesma coisa no navegador.

Componente Login:

```
<template>
  <div class='login'>
    <h1>Página de Login!!!</h1>
    <h1>Página de Login!!!</h1>
    <h1>Página de Login!!!</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Login',
}
</script>

<style>
.login {
  color: black;
}
</style>
```

Arquivo de rotas:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

import Content from '@/components/template/Content'
import Login from '@/components/account/Login'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [{
    name: 'content',
    path: '/',
    component: Content
}, {
    name: 'login',
    path: '/login',
    component: Login
}]

export default new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes
})
```

Arquivo App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Content />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Content from './components/template/Content'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: { Content }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa criar um `router-view` no na sua página principal, no caso o componente `App`, que irá direcionar para `Content` quando for `/` e para `Login` quando for `/login`.

Exemplo:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>Hello App!</h1>
  <p>
    <!-- use router-link component for navigation. -->
    <!-- specify the link by passing the `to` prop. -->
    <!-- `<router-link>` will be rendered as an `<a>` tag by default -->
    <router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link>
    <router-link to="/bar">Go to Bar</router-link>
  </p>
  <!-- route outlet -->
  <!-- component matched by the route will render here -->
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Exemplo tirado de https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html